# "TypeError: Knex is not a function" when configuring Knex with a connection to Supabase (PostgreSQL)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql, knex.js

i have this problem on configure knex with a connection to supebase (postegresql)

```
    Requiring external module ts-node/register
    Knex is not a function

    TypeError: Knex is not a function
        at Object.<anonymous>     (C:\LAVORO\MagickML\Magick\apps\server\node_modules\knex\knex.js:32:14)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
        at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js]     (C:\LAVORO\MagickML\Magick\apps\server\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1608:43)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
        at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
        at initKnex (C:\LAVORO\MagickML\Magick\apps\server\node_modules\knex\bin\cli.js:83:16)
        at async Command.<anonymous>     (C:\LAVORO\MagickML\Magick\apps\server\node_modules\knex\bin\cli.js:247:26)
```

this is my javascript knex file :

```
    const dotenv = require('dotenv');
    const Knex = require('knex');

    dotenv.config();

    const dbType = process.env.DATABASE_TYPE || 'pg';
    const dbURL = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'db.c*x*ah*ex*thvmin*ngo.supabase.co'; 

    const configs = {
      pg: {
        client: dbType,
        connection: {
          host: process.env.DB_HOST,
          port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
          user: process.env.DB_USER,
          password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
          database: process.env.DB_NAME,
          ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            ca: process.env.SUPABASE_CA_CERT,
          },
        },
      },
    };


    const knex = Knex (configs[dbType]);
    knex.knex = knex;
    knex.default = knex;

    module.exports = knex;
```

my .env:

```
    # Database
    DB_CLIENT=pg
    DB_HOST=db.*******************.supabase.co
    DB_PORT=****
    DB_USER=*****
    DB_PASSWORD=*****
    DB_NAME=******
```

(the asterisk aren't on my real code), i cannot figure out why i have this problem, i have the right dependencies setted in my package.json (required 2.4.2) and i think are right too my .env settings, Can someone help me by explaining what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't use `Knex`, but I'm going to say the issue is `const knex = Knex (configs[dbType]);`.  I don't see any such construct here [Knex starting](https://knexjs.org/guide/#node-js).

Comment: Your configs aren't the source of the problem. It has to be with your `require` and your knex package - try `console.log(Knex)` (or inspecting it) to see what it is. I normally use imports, i.e. `import knex from 'knex';` but that should really be the same thing.